# Wcf, ASP.NET MVC combination? Do I really need it?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture

Hello and Happy New Year all! While thinking about new project I decided to build my business layer as separate WCF services, that will be consumed by various clients. Data access is also handled by services. The first consumer is an ASP.NET MVC website and other clients will be created only in about a year or two. The question is do I really need WCF layer or it will be easy to rewrite this to only MVC and throw WCF away? Or keep things as is?

Comment: This vastly depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you build an MVC application or a desktop one, you will always need a Data Access Layer or Business Layer (Which ever name you choose for your Data Handling Objects).

I would suggest you to create a separate Project Which handles the task for data maniplulations.

And then Expose it via WCF Service and utlize it with any application whether web or desktop via different end points.

Answer (score 1):

The big clincher is that these services will be consumed by various clients. As you create other clients, you will be glad that created the services. The other alternative is to create the business layer as a DLL, but this could result in each client having different versions of the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of using WCF as a data access layer is that you can use many IIS web projects to connect to a single WCF web project. keep things organized.